# SQL query for multiple where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a table named `tbl_transactions` with columns

- `Category (string)`
- `for_month (string)`
- `Vehicle_No (string)`
- `amount (float)`

As shown below in the

[image: screenshot].

Is it possible to get the total amount for each month and the result should be category wise something like

[image: this]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the conditional aggregation as follows:

```
SELECT CATEGORY,
       SUM(CASE WHEN FOR_MONTH = 'April' THEN AMOUNT END) AS APRIL_AMOUNT,
       SUM(CASE WHEN FOR_MONTH = 'May' THEN AMOUNT END) AS MAY_AMOUNT,
       SUM(CASE WHEN FOR_MONTH = 'June' THEN AMOUNT END) AS JUNE_AMOUNT
 FROM YOUR_tABLE T
WHERE FOR_MONTH IN ('April', 'May', 'June')
 GROUP BY CATEGORY
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Popeye,

I'm getting below error, dont know where I went wrong.

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.

Comment: If it resolved your issue then please accept the answer so that this question is marked as resolved.

Comment: @syed : The Error is due to the Comma(,) before the FROM Clause. Plz Remove and Check the Same now

Comment: OMG, thanks a lot Popeye, appreciate your kind help.

Comment: Since I'm new here in Stackoverflow, don't know the rules, can I ask another question related to the same question?

Comment: You can ask another question as new question and we will be happy to help you :)

Comment: Just came to know that I have reached my question limit.

Comment: Since your months are in string, simplest solution is to use the month name as `SUM(CASE WHEN FOR_MONTH in ('Jan','Feb','Mar') THEN AMOUNT END) as q1_amount` in the same query

Answer (score 0):

Using **PIVOT**

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(Cat VARCHAR(MAX), Mon VARCHAR(MAX),Amt INT)


INSERT INTO @T VALUES('Registration','April',850),
('Registration','April',450),
('Registration','April',295)

SELECT Cat,  [April] AS [Total Amt in Apr], 
      [May] AS [Total Amt in May], 
    [June] AS [Total Amt in June]FROM   
(
 SELECT 
    Cat, 
    Mon,
    Amt
FROM 
   @T
) t 
PIVOT(
SUM(Amt) 
FOR Mon IN (
    [April], 
    [May], 
    [June]
  )
) AS pivot_table;
```

Results:

```
Cat            Total Amt in Apr   Total Amt in May  Total Amt in June 
Registration    1595               NULL              NULL
```

Comment: Thanks Thiyagu, luckily your solution also works for me..